# Iframe on bottom of every page

Tags: javascript, html, security, iframe

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this question, however I can't think of any other place where I can find answer to this.
I have noticed, this weird iframe on bottom of quite a few website. Weird because all of them same ip address. Here is screenshot from stackoverflow and bundler.io:
[image]
[image]

It may sound far fetched but could it be possible that someone is listening on me? I just concerned. I am using chrome: 41.0.2272.118 (64-bit)
and my os is ubuntu 14.04

I am talking about this:

```
   <iframe id="fn_layer8" src="http://223.224.131.144:80/l8/Layer8Servlet" target="_blank" frameborder="no" style="display: block !important; opacity: 0 !important; z-index: 2147483646 !important;">
    #document
    <html>
      <head>
        <style type="text/css"></style>
      </head>
      <body>
       <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;"></pre>
      </body>
     </html>
    </iframe>
<div id="fnscreenOverlay" style="position: fixed !important; bottom: 0px !important; left: 0px !important; top: auto !important; right: auto !important; height: 2571px !important; z-index: 2147483645 !important; width: 100% !important; text-align: center !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; border: 0px !important; opacity: 0 !important; display: none !important; background-color: transparent !important;"></div>
```

Comment: Seems dodgy for sure... Though this question doesn't really belong here. You might want to do some malware scan.

Comment: Whats the content of that iframe? Could you show us the code of it?

Comment: I have added complete code. Also, if not here where can I find definite answer?

Comment: If the problem is occurring on all websites rather than on sites you are creating, then it isn't a programming problem and something is up with your browser. This question is probably better suited to SuperUser.

Comment: This question has been reposted on [su]: [Iframe on bottom of every page](http://superuser.com/q/917711/53590)

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing this on pages that you normally wouldn't + sites that aren't connected in anyway (ie. same network) then there's a few reason I could think of (just speculation):

- Malware on your computer
- Browser add on that injects this iframe

If you open these sites in a different browser, does it still happen?  If not, then it's option 2.

I would look into some security software/malware removers.

Comment: I checked opera I found the same element. I am using ubuntu, are anitmalware even available for ubuntu? I guess I will have to look around.